# Website not loading/very slow only on a client's netwok

Tags: internet, lan, latency

I really need some help to explain following two scenarios as I only have little network troubleshooting skills.

I am supposed to go to these clients and give a valid reason for these issues. The only reason I could think here is "Slow network speed".

I know it could be hard to identify network problems just by reading this post, but at least few suggestions, comments or troubleshooting tips you can give help me a lot here.

**Case 1:**

We did a website for a client. This website has a page that loads around < 2500 MySql records. We have loaded this page in several different networks. All of them took 1-2 minutes to load the whole page without any problems.
However, when we load this website on **client's network** it takes hours(or sometimes doesn't event load).

**Case 2:**

We did another website for a client. It works fine on other networks, but only in **client's network**, it has wired behaviours. Sometimes website loads partially. We can see links appearing on a white background without any CSS/JS and not working.
Sometimes it doesn't even load.

---

Please Note:

1. Both websites can be loaded in other networks and they behave fine.
2. Both clients have good internet connections and able to visit other
   sites like google/facebook etc. without any problems. All other
   popular sites working just fine except our custom built sites.
3. We are unable to change the architecture of the website. ex: Implement pagination.

Website info:

1. PHP > 5
2. MySql
3. Http
4. Using HostSG as the Service Provider

---

Can you please tell me what possible reasons causing these problems?
Is there any way to identify the exact problem?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: It sounds like you are referring to a clients' network for which you have no control over, which would be off topic here.

Comment: You'll need to go to "client network" and see what's what.

Comment: Can you guys give me some tips to identify the problem? I can go to client's place and check and stuff.

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the topology of your clients' networks, I'd hazard a guess that this is an MTU issue. Ask your clients to investigate their network devices' configurations and lower their MTU (maximum transmission unit) and/or MSS (maximum segment size) if necessary. Fore more information on MTU and MSS, see [my blog post entry](http://www.oznetnerd.com/2013/05/24/mtu-vs-mss-part-two/).